# Cleaning up fuzzy duplicates and standardization of rows in Python(Pandas)

Tags: python, excel, pandas, duplicates, fuzzy

anyone knows how to do a cleanup of fuzzy duplicates and establish some kind of convention within similar items such as in the picture? My data is in excel and would want to automate analyzing, removal and replacement of a chosen standard per group of similar items.

[**before and after**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcI0N.jpg)

Comment: you want to remove them?? `df[df['Place(before)'].ne(df['Place(After)'])]` ??

Comment: I want to determine a standard label among groups, then use them to replace the fuzzy duplicates.